# Is it possible to change method type annotations for a class instance?

Tags: python, annotations, metaprogramming

I have a class which takes in some arguments, with a method that takes and returns a namedtuple.  The namedtuple itself is defined within the **init** based on some inputs, e.g.:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, input_fields: List[str], output_fields: List[str]):
        self.input_spec = namedtuple("MyClassInputs", input_fields)
        self.output_spec = namedtuple("MyClassOutputs", output_fields)
    
    def my_method(self, inputs):
        # do stuff
        return outputs
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, input_fields, output_fields):
        self.input_spec = namedtuple("MyClassInputs", input_fields)
        self.output_spec = namedtuple("MyClassOutputs", output_fields)

        register_type_hints(self.my_method, self.input_spec, self.output_spec)

    def my_method(self, inputs):
        # do stuff
        return outputs


def register_type_hints(method, input_spec, output_spec):
    signature = inspect.signature(method)
    new_parameter = signature.parameters["inputs"].replace(annotation=input_spec)
    new_signature = signature.replace(
            parameters=[new_parameter], return_annotation=output_spec
        )
    method.__signature__ = new_signature
    method.__annotations__ = {"inputs": input_spec, "return": output_spec}
```

the result is that the method now has the type hints:

```
def my_method(self, inputs: MyClassInputs) -> MyClassOutputs:
    # do stuff
    return outputs
```

`register_type_hints` it seems would work if this were a function, but for an instance method it doesn't like it.

Comment: Python's type hint system is almost entirely focused around static typing, while what you're trying to do needs dynamic typing. Type hints aren't going to be useful here.

Comment: I agree with @user2357112supportsMonica.  The typing arguments are for static type checkers and development environments.  Setting the type at runtime doesn't really gain you anything.   There is no type checking at runtime.

Comment: What do you hope to gain by doing this?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was originally trying to hack the torch.jit compiler, it does respect type hints for compliation, but it parses the code itself so the method signature is meaningless to it.